# type error : null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.isLoading')

Tags: listview, react-native

**i have initialized the state but what is happening**

---

- already imported nessesary stuffs

  ```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator ,ListView , Alert , Text, View } from 'react-native';

  export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.states = {
    isLoading : true ,
  dataSource: {}
  };
  }
     componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
           method: 'GET' ,
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
           console.log(responseJson);
           Alert.alert("done");
           this.setState({
              data: responseJson ,
              isLoading: false
  ```

  })
        })

  .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);

  });
         }
        render() {
          if(!this.state.isLoading){
            return (
      
              );
          }
          else {
            return (
      
               {item.body}}
              />
            
            );
          }

  ```
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
     flex: 1,
     paddingTop: 22
    },
    item: {
      padding: 15,
      borderBottomWidth: 2 ,
      borderBottomColor: '#888888' ,
      fontSize: 18,
      height: 54,
    },
  })
  ```
- and i just called the this.state
- *why is this happening anybody who have right now*

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it appear you have spelled `this.state` as `this.states` in the constructor...

```
...
this.states = {
  isLoading : true ,
  dataSource: {}
};...
```

change `this.states` to `this.state`  :)